# How to inject different implementation classes when using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I have the following structure:

```
public interface MyService{
  public void someMethod();
}

@Service
public class MyServiceImplA implements MyService {
  public void someMethod() {
       return;
}
```

and in my controller, I do this:

```
@Autowired
MyServiceImplA myService;

   myService.somemethod();
```

I am not sure how I should be using the interface here?  What happens if I have a second implementation, say MyServiceImplB?  Can I set this through some sort of configuration (I am using Java Config)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Service("fooService")
public class MyServiceImplA implements MyService {    
    //..
}
```

and

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fooService")
MyService myService;
```